# UIRefreshControl with transparent background above UISearchController

Tags: ios, uisearchcontroller, uirefreshcontrol

I have implemented a UIRefreshControl with transparent background in a table, and all was working fine until I added a UIRefreshControl, now I can't remove the gray background behind the RefreshControl as shown in the screenshots.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dBGM3.png)

Anybody knows where could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Double-check the background color of the TableView:

[image: TableView background color]

> 2. Double-check the background color of the UIRefreshControl itself:

[image: UIRefreshControl background color]